# for loop compilation errors

Tags: java, syntax

```
public class contains {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    int sum = 0;
    for (i=0, i<=array.length, i++) {
        if (array[i] == 4) {
            return sum;
        }
        sum++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}

I'm not sure why this code above fails. When I try to compile it, I get errors like below. Why is this happening? I want to see at what index 4 is at in my array.

```
contains.java:5: error: not a statement
    for (i=0, i<=array.length, i++) {
               ^
contains.java:5: error: ';' expected
    for (i=0, i<=array.length, i++) {
                                  ^
contains.java:5: error: ';' expected
    for (i=0, i<=array.length, i++) {
                                   ^
contains.java:6: error: illegal start of expression
        if (array[i] == 4) {
        ^
contains.java:6: error: ')' expected
        if (array[i] == 4) {
          ^
contains.java:6: error: not a statement
        if (array[i] == 4) {
                     ^
contains.java:6: error: ';' expected
        if (array[i] == 4) {
                         ^
contains.java:11: error: illegal start of type
        return 0;
```

Comment: [Voting to close as typo.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: But you also need a return type other than `void` if you're going to use a return statement with a value.

Comment: [Java tutorial for beginners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: You never defined a type for i. also you never closed the class declaration with a }

Comment: You're also using `,`s instead of `;` inbetween the expressions in your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare `i`. The parts of a `for` loop are seperated by a semi-colon. Java arrays have an initial index of `0`, and the last element is at `array.length - 1` so you need `<` (not `<=`). You can't `return` an `int` from `main`. I think you wanted something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == 4) {
            break;
        }
        sum++;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Output is

```
4
```

And `array[4]` is `4` so I believe the sum should be `4`.